# How do I create a user's profile info document on sign up with Firestore / SwiftUI?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Quick edit: The user is able to be authed totally fine, just no document creation.

I feel like I'm overcomplicating this. I've tried searching everywhere but I haven't been able to find a solution that works without forcing me to restructure my app. Everything else works except for this, and I feel I just need to place the call to the `createUserDoc` function in the right place, but I just don't know where. This is what I currently have. I've tried to skim out as much filler as I could. The sign up form is your generic textfield VStack, so I don't think that's needed

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var email: String
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
}

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    @Published var session: User?
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    let authRef = Auth.auth()
    
    func listen() {
        handle = authRef.addStateDidChangeListener({ auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                self.session = User(id: user.uid, email: user.email!)
            } else {
                self.session = nil
            }
        })
    }
 
    // ...

    func signUp(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, password: String) {
        authRef.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            guard error != nil else { return }
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            
            // This is what I don't know where to put
            self.db.collection("Users").document(user.uid).setData([
                "firstName": firstName,
                "lastName": lastName,
                "email": email,
                "id": user.uid

            // I've also tried using the createUserDoc function
            let newUser = User(id: user.uid, email: email, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
            self.createUserDoc(newUser: newUser)
            
        ])

        }
        
    }

    // ...
    
    func createUserDoc(newUser: User) {
        let _ = db.collection("Users").document(newUser.id).setData([
                "firstName": newUser.firstName,
                "lastName": newUser.lastName,
                "email": newUser.email,
                "id": newUser.id
        ])
    }
}
```

Based off searching, I think I have an idea of what is going wrong, I just don't know what to do about it. I think it's that the `signUp` function has to complete before executing `createUserDoc`. But I need to reference that user's uid to create the doc in the first place. I kinda (barely) have an idea of a quick fix solution by creating a throwaway class, only for creating a document, but that feels wrong and redundant, plus I'd have to introduce a bunch of pointless, throwaway variables and extra code.

Ideally, signing up and creating document should happen all in one function, right? How do I go about doing that? I would really appreciate a suggestion that minimizes restructuring if possible. I've had enough restructurings for a week and I finally have something I can follow and understand.

Comment: Are you positive you're not getting an error? You're just returning and not printing the error or anything in the `guard` statement.

Comment: @jnpdx That's a good question, after restarting so many times I did not care too much about implementing the error handling. Will find out soon

Comment: @jnpdx Well turns out it was getting caught up in the guard error statement. I changed it to if let error = error and everything went through as intended. Can't say what the problem was before, but either way thank you for reminding me to build and test more often, will do that more from here on out.

Comment: Oh yeah -- looking at it more closely, you have `guard let error != nil` which should've been the opposite: `guard error == nil`

Comment: Oh jesus lol, my Python background is having a hard time adjusting to Swift, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jnpdx I was able to fix it. Turns out I had to change the `guard error != nil` statement to `if let error = error`. I don't know why this works and it didn't before but let this be a reminder to all fellow newbies: Build and test every once in a while, even if your laptop is on the verge of exploding while building.